# Navigate with tabIndex when elements where hidden

Tags: reactjs

## Summary

I want to understand how the tabulation navigation works on browser, in order to perform custom input with suggestion field on React.

## Objective

The objective is to provide 2 custom input to the use with suggestion dropdown. When I click to my input, the dropdown shows correctly and I can navigate through the tabulation key to my suggestions. But when I try to navigate to the next input, the dropdown shows but I can't navigate through my second dropdown suggestion.

## Code example

I have the following JSX code:

```js
class InputDropdown  React.Component {
    render() {
        return(<div>
                <div id="input1" className="input-wrapper" onMouseEnter={...} onMouseLeave={...} onBlur={...}>
                    <input className={"input"} 
                        value={this.state.search_input} 
                        onKeyDown={(e) => e.keyCode==13?this.props.validate(this.state.search_input)}
                        onFocus={this.setState(display_dropdown_input1: true)}
                        />
                    <div className={"dropdown-wrapper" + this.state.display_dropdown_input1?"":"hidden"}>
                        {this.props.suggestion.map((suggestion, index) => 
                            <div className="suggestion"
                                tabIndex={0}
                                onKeyDown={(e) => e.keyCode==13?this.props.validate(suggestion.text)}
                                onBlur={index+1==this.props.suggestion.length?this.setState({display_dropdown_input1:false})}
                            >{suggestion.text}</div>)}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="input2" className="input-wrapper" onMouseEnter={...} onMouseLeave={...} onBlur={...}>
                    <input className={"input"} 
                        value={this.state.search_input} 
                        onKeyDown={(e) => e.keyCode==13?this.props.validate(this.state.search_input)}
                        onFocus={this.setState(display_dropdown_input2: true)}
                        />
                    <div className={"dropdown-wrapper" + this.state.display_dropdown_input2?"":"hidden"}>
                        {this.props.suggestion.map((suggestion, index) => 
                            <div className="suggestion"
                                tabIndex={0}
                                onKeyDown={(e) => e.keyCode==13?this.props.validate(suggestion.text)}
                                onBlur={index+1==this.props.suggestion.length?this.setState({display_dropdown_input2:false})}
                            >{suggestion.text}</div>)}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>)
    }
}
```

## Question

It's as if the tabulation navigations road is prepared on the first tabulation pressed and if element appear after this press they are not taken in count.

Is it possible to perform it in React?

Comment: can you please review your code?
this `this.setState(display_dropdown_input2:false)` does not look right

Comment: @AlexandrZavalii I fixed the code. But the above code is not exactly the code I have written on my local machine. As I have an integration library, i rewrite the code in pure React to help everyone to understand the problems. I didn't test if there were typo in the code